# Variable in string is not being replaced?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I want my image to be the status' name ("ok.png" for example).

I've tried:

```
link_to '<img src="images/#{refactoredStatus}.png">'.html_safe, '#', :class => 'option show_status'
```

But that literally shows `images/#{refactoredStatus}.png` in my HTML.

How do I do this?

Comment: Hint: How does `'string from single quote literal'` differ from `"string from double quote literal"`? See some [applicable reference material](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
link_to image_tag("#{refactoredStatus}.png"), '#', :class => 'option show_status'
```

This uses the Rails `image_tag` helper instead.

**Edit:**

If you're set on using HTML instead of the `image_tag` helper then you can do this:

```
link_to "<img src=\"images/#{refactoredStatus}.png\">".html_safe, '#', :class => 'option show_status'
```

or this:

```
link_to %{<img src="images/#{refactoredStatus}.png">}.html_safe, '#', :class => 'option show_status'
```

I personally prefer the last solution because you don't have to escape the quotes.

Comment: While this does indeed use the image_tag helper, which is good, this *isn't* the change that "solves" the problem/issue.

Answer (score -1):

Ruby is reading that as a string. The proper way to do this is using the image tag, so:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('foobar.png'), '#' %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: While this does show the usage of `image_tag`, it doesn't address how to interpolate the variable.